# What is a literary style to reinterpret this situation in a phrase?

Tags: phrase-meaning

"I don't had to take the full 120 college credit for this post-baccalaureate bachelor degree instead I just need to take 60 credit."

What is a more advanced way to reinterpret that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't had to take the full 120 college credit for this post-baccalaureate bachelor degree instead I just need to take 60 credit.

The above sentence can be written as one of the following two sentence alternatives:

- This post-baccalaureate bachelor's degree does not require me to
  receive one hundred and twenty credits. Instead, it requires me to receive just sixty credits.
- This post-baccalaureate bachelor's degree does not require me to get
  one hundred and twenty credits. Instead, it requires me to get just sixty
  credits.
- This post-baccalaureate bachelor's degree does not require me to gain
  one hundred and twenty credits. Instead, it requires me to gain just sixty
  credits.
  (Use can use get/achieve/receive/gain in the above sentences)

The above sentence can be written as one of the following one sentence alternatives:

- My post-baccalaureate bachelor's degree does not require one hundred
  and twenty credits, just sixty credits.

(The above example makes the sentence more direct since I have used "my" in the sentence to indicate possession of the degree by the person)